# Check if a monthly charge has been made in Stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I'm building a web app, which has a place, that only a premium user can get to. How can I check if the user paid and is premium? Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
var time = req.params.time;
console.log(time);
if (time === '1') {
    var amount = 1499;
    var days = 30;
}
else if (time === '3') {
    amount = 999 * 3;
    days = 90;
}
else res.render('payment/error', {title: 'Error', user: req.user});
//^^^^ error/security handling ^^^^//

console.log(req.user.username);
stripe.charges.create({
    amount: amount,
    currency: "cad",
    source: req.body.stripeToken,
    description: "Charge for DigitLead website evaluation tool",
    receipt_email: req.user.username,
}).then(ch => {
    console.log(ch);
    Account.findById(req.user._id).then(u => {
        var date = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(date);
        u.lastPaid = date;
        date += (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        console.log(date);
        u.premiumEnds = date;
        console.log(u);
        u.save();
        res.render('payment/summary', {
            title: 'Payment Summary',
            user: req.user,
            date: u.premiumEnds,
        })
    });
}).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

But I don't like this, because if I need to make more changes to the payment system in the future it'll take me forever to do it like this. Can I do it with Stripe API or do I have to use my own code? I'm grateful for other suggestions as well.

This is my model. I know I'll need to change it

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var plm = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    accType: String,
    websites: [],
    keys: [],
    creditCardNo: Number,
    alexaCalls: Number,
    stripeId: String,
    lastPaid: Date,
    premiumEnds: Date,
});

accountSchema.plugin(plm);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', accountSchema);
```

Comment: Why don't you use the subscribtions api for subscriptions? I'd first create one, then use stripe's webhooks to let your database be updated automatically. If the user hasn't paid, you can block their account on next login or with another logic you like best

Comment: Ok that is one way. So the logic would be: Every time the payment is done, my property (for example isPremium) would be set to true. But how would I know if the user didn't pay?

Comment: Just take the Date and check if the last successful payment is less than  1 month back, I wouldn't say you need to store isPremium at all. The check with the Date should suffice

Comment: Sounds good. I'll try to implement it. Would you like to add an answer so I can select it?

Comment: @baao Could you point me to the right point in the documentation? I created the subscription and all, but cannot see the date of last payment anywhere.

Comment: Go over to webhooks. They will get triggered when any action occurs, e.g. a payment. Here’s the documentation for webhooks with subscriptions. https://stripe.com/docs/billing/webhooks. Stripe will send you all the details automatically then

Comment: Can you figure it out with that?

Comment: Heya!  Stripe person here and @baao is totally right.  Yes, you definitely can figure it out with webhooks.  You'll listen for `invoice.payment_failed` or `invoice.payment_succeeded` events.  They'll have a `created`-attribute and a `subscription`-attribute that will give you everything you need.  Hope that helps!